# Questions with "assignment" in them should have automatic warning

Tags: feature-request

On the main SO site, any questions with the word "best" in them have a warning automatically displayed:

> [image: warning for question with "best" in title]

Based on some recent questions [[1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/453/class-assignmet)][[2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/452/open-ended-final-assignment)], I want to propose a similar warning for our site if the question has "assignment" in it, with the following wording:

> Your question appears limited in scope... [please ensure it's within site guidelines](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) before posting.

Comments?

Comment: I agree, I've been trying to come up with a question that would contain the word "assignment" and still be relevant to this site, and I couldn't find any. And as long as it is just a warning, that can't harm.

Comment: In the first example you give 'assignment' was actually misspelt in the submission version ('assignmet', based on the URL), so ironically this wouldn't have flagged it...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a pretty clever idea, but it should probably be phrased somewhat softer than the Stack Overflow warning for "best". Because, for example, there's some teaching related questions that I can see having 'assignment' in the title, and we don't want to drive those away.

Comment: That's a good point, I've been trying to think of the best language. I've updated the text, what do you think?

Comment: I like it better. It should function as a warning/note rather than the much stronger "You're thread's probably going to get closed"

Comment: This works for now; we can revise as needed if it doesn't appear to be getting the job done.